# Cannot return json object as string

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I have an C# function that return String datatype. I want to return an json object as string , but I got this error: CS1002: ; expected
Here is function:

```
    public String LoginUser(string Username, string Password)
   {
               string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
               try
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login_User");
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                   cmd.Connection = con;
                   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                   {
                       con.Open();
                   }
                   SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                   if (rd.HasRows)
                   {
                       rd.Read();
                       return "{"message": "Successfully"}"; //me sukses
                   }

                   else
                       return "{"message": "Invalid Username and/or Password"}"; //pas sukses
               }

               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   throw ex;
               }
               finally
               {
                   if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                   {
                       con.Close();
                   }
               }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you need [escape `"` character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) in both string as;

```
return "{\"message\": \"Successfully\"}"; //me sukses
```

and

```
return "{\"message\": \"Invalid Username and/or Password\"}";
```

Or use verbatim string literals as with doubling them;

```
return @"{""message"": ""Invalid Username and/or Password""}";
```

and

```
return "{""message"": ""Invalid Username and/or Password""}";
```

Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections, commands and readers automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Bu the way I strongly suspect you keep your passwords as a plaint text. **Don't do that**. Read [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

Comment: but when I consume this method with JQuery, Response format in browser is displayed with slashes /  . I want to remove slashes from object when is returned in browser !!! how can I do this ?

Comment: I want to return result without \   . I want to remove all  /  from object when is returned in browser !!! how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` before your string to easily escape your double quotes.

```
return @"{"message": "Invalid Username and/or Password"}";
```

Try changing:

```
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                  throw ex;  // don't do this
           }
```

To:

```
           catch (SqlException ex)
           {
               return string.Format("error: {0}", ex.message);
           }
```